# Remove an item from array in groovy

Tags: arrays, jenkins, groovy, key-value

The array which i have in groovy is not getting recognized. How to remove an item within an array based on condition

If this is my array

```
def list = [   
  [prerelease: 'true',  surname: 'surname'],
  [prerelease: 'true',  surname: 'surname'],
  [prerelease: 'false', surname: 'surname']
]

list.removeAll(list.findAll{it.prerelease == 'true'})
println list
```

I get the following output

```
[[prerelease:false, surname:surname]]
```

If my array is in this format

```
def list1 = [   
  {prerelease: 'true',  surname: 'surname'},
  {prerelease: 'true',  surname: 'surname'},
  {prerelease: 'false', surname: 'surname'}
]
```

Then i get the following error

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/home/cg/root/2646066/main.groovy: 2: unexpected token: true @ line 2, column 16.
     {prerelease: 'true',  surname: 'surname'},
```

I need to make the list1 work. Is there anyway it will work in groovy if my array is in the above format with "{" parenthesis

List1 is an output from bash hence it's in this format. I need to use this array in groovy to remove some items from array. Bash script to generate the array is called from groovy. Output of that bash script returns an array like this.

Comment: `{...}` is incorrect for groovy key-value map declaration. it could be json and groovy could parse json with JsonSlurper. but for groovy itself it's a wrong syntax

Comment: a list can not be in "this" or "another" format, it's either compilable or not

Comment: List1 is an output from bash hence it's in this format. I need to use this array in groovy to remove some items from array.

Comment: Can you please show us how exactly do you assign the output to a variable? Outputs from shell usually come as text (and are assigned as text), therefore what you assign manually above is completely wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you need to get it as a text with a command similar to this one:
`def List1AsText= sh(returnStdout: true, script: "PUT SHELL COMMAND TO GET THE LIST HERE").trim()`

Answer (score 0):

Idk the exact output that you want. But this code is what I understand

```
def list = [   
  [prerelease: 'true',  surname: 'surname'],
  [prerelease: 'true',  surname: 'surname'],
  [prerelease: 'false', surname: 'surname']
]

def newList = []
list.each { value ->
 if(value.prerelease == 'true') {
  list.remove(value.prerelease)
 } else {
  newList.add(value)
 }
}
println newList
```

Output

```
[[prerelease: 'true',  surname: 'surname'],[prerelease: 'true',  surname: 'surname']]
```